# Type casting problems with template class

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I've following code and i want to store `MyClass<int>,MyClass<float>`...  in a `vector<BaseClass> mItems` then recover the original class.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way in C++ to cast from base class to templated class, but still now i can not find the way how to do it.

`MyClass<int> lRecover1 = dynamic_cast<MyClass<int>>(mItems.at(0));`

This doesn't compile, and I don't understand why. Here is my code if it helps:

```
#include <vector>

class BaseClass
{
public:

    virtual ~BaseClass() {}
};


template<typename T>
class MyClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {

    }

    ~MyClass()
    {

    }

};

void main()
{
    std::vector<BaseClass> mItems;

    MyClass<int> lItem1, lItem2;
    MyClass<float> lItem3, lItem4, lItem5;
    MyClass<double> lItem6, lItem7;


    //PROBLEM: I would like to recover the original class
    MyClass<int> lRecover1 = dynamic_cast<MyClass<int>>(mItems.at(0));
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388643/downcasting-non-template-base-class-to-templated-derived-class-is-it-possible

Comment: You can only cast pointers and references.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029868/create-a-vector-of-base-class-objects-and-store-derived-class-objects-within

Answer (score 2):

A vector of `BaseClass` instances will only contain actual instances of `BaseClass` by value. A vector of `BaseClass*` instances will contain pointers to `BaseClass` or any of its children.

```
std::vector<BaseClass*> items;
...
MyClass<int>* recover = dynamic_cast<MyClass<int>*>(items.at(0));
```

When you're dealing with the possibility of subclasses, you must always have a layer of indirection using either pointers or references. (And you have to use pointers in this case since references cannot be stored in an `std::vector`)

In particular, if you were to try to store `MyClass<int>` instances in a container of type `std::vector<BaseClass>`, C++ would try to copy the instances into the vector, using `BaseClass`'s copy constructor. This would lead to `BaseClass` copying the data that it knows about and failing to copy the child class information, effectively losing the extra data, a problem commonly referred to as [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).